# Calling $parse function with parameters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have an attribute that is a function and I parse that attribute, but when I call the function, the function doesn't include any parameters.

```js
// main ctrl
$scope.fn = function (attr) {
  console.log(attr);
};


// directive
$attrs.$observe('vFn', function (f) {
  $scope.fn = $parse(f);
});


$scope.fn($scope, {attribute: 'This is not passed'});
```

```html
<div v-fn="fn()"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the parameter in the directive call. Try this.

```
<div v-fn="fn(attribute)"
```